# Get java object in thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am passing a list of java pojo to a data table, and I have to show details which are in a list in the same class, I must show this details in the second datatable when I click on a row on the first datatable which contain the pojos. 
I was wondering if there is a way to get back the object again when I click on it to show its details in the second table. 
Ps: for confidentiality reasons at my work I can't show what I did, so I'm not asking to code for me, just to know if it's achievable if yes just a hint to resolve it.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think it will depend on how is the second table being displayed.
If it's an entirely different page there won't be any reference. If it's a single page application, you can render the second table and just use js/css to hide it until selected.

may not be the best approach

Comment: Thank you for your answer, how do you think it is achievable as it's same page? How can I do such render and how do you think I'll identify which data to render or to show?  Thank you

Comment: If there unique id's for the pojos you can probably use that as an id for the secondary tables, and use js/css to hide/show the object when appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is achievable. Make a unique id for each of the pojo in the list. Then put html anchors for every pojo in data table that point to the details controller. When it clicked, make it going to details controller with the details rendered in separate html view.

May [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-crud-thymeleaf) help